# Adding Line to Clustered Column Chart

Tags: powerbi, graphing

Can anyone tell me why my "line value" is converted to a "count" when attempting to add this field? It's stored as a percentage and would need it to show as a percentage. Having multiple Y axis would be beneficial for this visual.

The first attachment is what I have. The second attachment is what I'm trying to create.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is it stored as a percentage? Is it for example 0.5 or text like 50%. It looks like your datatype is not set as an float type or in measure, and has been dragged into the 'Line Values'. Anything not a float or int will automatically be a count.

Comment: Hi Jon- Is there anyway to do that within PBI? Only Data Type options I'm seeing are: whole number, decimal, fixed decimal.

Comment: Set it as decimal, in the query editor you can also set it to percentage, if its in the  format of 0.5 it will display as 50%